# In ZSH line editor, how to insert a new line?

Tags: zsh

Say I am editing a single line, with my cursor at the indicated position:

```
$ abc ꕯ def ghi
```

I would now like to split into two lines and continue editing (like hitting ENTER would do in a text editor):

```
$ abc
$ ꕯ def ghi
```

Is there a way to do this in ZSH?

Comment: Should `abc` be executed or do you want to insert a `\n` character at the cursor position?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### In ZLE's `emacs` mode:

… the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> character (ASCII `SYN`) is bound to the `quoted-insert` widget.  So just enter <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (ASCII `LF`).

### In ZLE's `vi` mode:

… the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (ASCII `DC1`) and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> characters are bound to the `vi-quoted-insert` widget.  So again, in insert mode, just enter <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

### Remember:

Newlines in the middle of command lines separate commands.  (In the terminology of the `zsh` manual: both newline and `;` terminate a *list*.)  Quote the newline if you don't want that.

Comment: I was able to bind the emacs mode to Shift + Enter to automatically insert a quoted insert. However since I switched to the vim mode, it doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work in vim mode?

Comment: In emacs mode, you can also insert a newline with M-Return.

Comment: I suspect you mean to **escape** the newline (with a backslash) if you don't want that newline to separate commands. A quoted newline (e.g. `$'\n'`) is merely a string with a single NL char in it which is going to be sent as an argument to the command.

Answer (score 6):

Use ⌥↩︎ (<kbd>Option / Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Return</kbd>), or ⎋, ↩︎ (<kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>Return</kbd>).

This will only work if you've called `bindkey -e` previously or somewhere in your .zshrc.

Comment: PS: **This also works in OS X**! If you press ⌥↩︎ in, say, the Messages box, you'll get a new line. Doesn't work in SE comment boxes, though. (:

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the answer that I was looking for. Usually line-break is done using `shift + enter` but seems like linux does stuff differently. Thanks a lot for the concise and straightforward answer!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "vimmer" way in ZLE vi-mode that does not involve `ctrl` chords.

if your line looks like follows, and you are in **normal** mode:
    $ abc ꕯ def ghi

type this: <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

total key presses: 4.

explanation:

```
`D` cuts from cursor to the end of the line and places cut string in register
`o`opens a new line places the cursor in it, and switches to insert mode
`<esc>` switches to normal pode
`p` paste register content.
```