# How to insert special characters with zsh line editor?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh

In vim we can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>Number</kbd> in insert mode to insert special characters. This is mostly used to insert control characters. But any characters can be inserted if we know the ASCII number. E.g. typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd> will insert a '~' character.
See: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ins-special-keys
I'd like to have the same or similar behaviour with zsh line editor. Note, I am using zsh in vi mode, but I don't think that matters.
I've found that inserting an enter can be done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>, see:
[In ZSH line editor, how to insert a new line?](https://superuser.com/questions/719138/in-zsh-line-editor-how-to-insert-a-new-line). But how do I insert a tilde?

I need this, becasue 
I am working with a dumb citrix client, with which I cannot type the '~' character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possibilities (`~` has the ASCII code 126 or 176 in decimal or octal notation, resp.):

- use the `$'\OCT'` syntax, where `OCT` is the ASCII code in octal notation:

  ```
  $ echo foo$'\176'bar
  foo~bar
  ```
- use command substitution with printf:

  ```
  $ echo foo$(printf "\176")bar
  foo~bar
  ```
- use this zle widget to resemble vi'S special char input:

  ```
  insert-special-char() {
    LBUFFER+=$(printf "\x$(printf %x $NUMERIC)")
  }
  zle -N insert-special-char
  ```

  where I borrowed the printf line from [broaden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1754931/2037712).

  To use this widget, bind it to e.g. `S` in zle's vi-command-mode (or any other key you don't use):

  ```
  bindkey -M vicmd "S" insert-special-char
  ```

  Then type in the ASCII-Code (in decimal notation) while in zle's vi-command-mode and press `S`. Then the special character is inserted:

  <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: The problem with the first two options is that they do not handle the path expansion correctly. Here is what I mean:
```
--> % ls $'\176'
ls: ~: No such file or directory
```
So ~ is not expanded to the absolute path of my home directory.
However option 3 is working properly as if I just had typed the '~' character.

Comment: @GaborMarton: I see... perhaps `ls $HOME` is an easier-to-type alternative for you.